# installation of magento2 step 1 have 500 error

Tags: magento2

**When i check the log error the following errors are showing:**

> [24-Oct-2016 13:04:59 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No wrapper found supporting "UTF-8"' in /home/brasilmart/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-stdlib/src/StringUtils.php:135
>   Stack trace:

Comment: Can you please post steps followed for installation?

Comment: i download magento2 and then upload to cpanel/public_html directory.  when i go to my base url [link](http://www.brasilmart.net/) it show 500 error and when i will check error log its show 'Zend\Stdlib\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'No wrapper found supporting "UTF-8"'

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing some PHP extensions; check [this stackexchange article](http://mrgott.com/magento/26-how-to-install-magento-2-using-the-command-line-on-a-shared-server) then review the extensions you need in the [install guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/prereq-overview.html).